# AsyncUDP example on two ESP32s not working: "WL_NO_SSID_AVAIL"

Tags: udp, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266, esp32

I am attempting to create a direct Client-Server WiFi network between two [ESP32 DEVKITV1s](https://au.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Espressif-Systems/ESP32-DevKitC-32U?qs=%252BEew9%252B0nqrCEVvpkdH%2FG5Q%3D%3D&vip=1&gclid=CjwKCAiAx_DwBRAfEiwA3vwZYsD0n7KaDE-suGEfjqcaYepT9N6LH7mmmEdHB6oR5zFtNSopI5qHRBoCQmkQAvD_BwE) powered by my two computer's USB ports.

I have loaded the example using the Arduino IDE (with the additional boards manager URL https://dl.espressif.com/dl/package_esp32_index.json) and the WiFi status (on both boards) is *WL_NO_SSID_AVAIL*.

**The client code:**

```
#include "WiFi.h"
#include "AsyncUDP.h"

const char * ssid = "my_ssid";
const char * password = "my_password";

AsyncUDP udp;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    if (WiFi.waitForConnectResult() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        Serial.println("WiFi Failed");
        while(1) {
            delay(1000);
        }
    }
    if(udp.connect(IPAddress(192,168,1,100), 1234)) {
        Serial.println("UDP connected");
        udp.onPacket([](AsyncUDPPacket packet) {
            Serial.print("UDP Packet Type: ");
            Serial.print(packet.isBroadcast()?"Broadcast":packet.isMulticast()?"Multicast":"Unicast");
            Serial.print(", From: ");
            Serial.print(packet.remoteIP());
            Serial.print(":");
            Serial.print(packet.remotePort());
            Serial.print(", To: ");
            Serial.print(packet.localIP());
            Serial.print(":");
            Serial.print(packet.localPort());
            Serial.print(", Length: ");
            Serial.print(packet.length());
            Serial.print(", Data: ");
            Serial.write(packet.data(), packet.length());
            Serial.println();
            //reply to the client
            packet.printf("Got %u bytes of data", packet.length());
        });
        //Send unicast
        udp.print("Hello Server!");
    }
}

void loop()
{
    delay(1000);
    //Send broadcast on port 1234
    udp.broadcastTo("Anyone here?", 1234);
}
```

**The server code:**

```
#include "WiFi.h"
#include "AsyncUDP.h"

const char * ssid = "my_ssid";
const char * password = "my_password";

AsyncUDP udp;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    if (WiFi.waitForConnectResult() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        Serial.println("WiFi Failed");
        while(1) {
            delay(1000);
        }
    }
    if(udp.listen(1234)) {
        Serial.print("UDP Listening on IP: ");
        Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
        udp.onPacket([](AsyncUDPPacket packet) {
            Serial.print("UDP Packet Type: ");
            Serial.print(packet.isBroadcast()?"Broadcast":packet.isMulticast()?"Multicast":"Unicast");
            Serial.print(", From: ");
            Serial.print(packet.remoteIP());
            Serial.print(":");
            Serial.print(packet.remotePort());
            Serial.print(", To: ");
            Serial.print(packet.localIP());
            Serial.print(":");
            Serial.print(packet.localPort());
            Serial.print(", Length: ");
            Serial.print(packet.length());
            Serial.print(", Data: ");
            Serial.write(packet.data(), packet.length());
            Serial.println();
            //reply to the client
            packet.printf("Got %u bytes of data", packet.length());
        });
    }
}

void loop()
{
    delay(1000);
    //Send broadcast
    udp.broadcast("Anyone here?");
}
```

Has anyone else had problems running the example code on their ESP32 using the Arduino IDE?

Comment: run the wifiscan example

Comment: Thanks @Juraj! Great idea. I ran the WiFiScan, but only got my home WiFi network, nothing named "my_ssid". When I changed the WiFi.mode from *WIFI_STA* to *WIFI_AP_STA* it found the old SSID that I had used on the ESP32 (not the new one) from a circuits4you.com tutorial I had tried earlier. 

Additionally, it was only listed every other scan (with the remaining scans only showing the home network and not the ESP32).

Is there something I need to do with the ESP32 to reset all of the effects of the previous firmware?

Comment: you want one esp32 to be an AP? then start the AP. you can configure the name of the SoftAP. there is no relation between TCP client/server and SoftAP and connected stations. one of the stations can be a TCP server. the esp with SoftAP can be one of the TCP clients

Comment: Cool. It's good to know that the SoftAP and station settings are not the problem because they don't have a bearing on the client-server example.

But I don't think it explains why the example code doesn't appear to work with my ESP32s and code above.

Comment: `WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);` https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/WiFi/examples/WiFiAccessPoint/WiFiAccessPoint.ino

Comment: Thanks @Juraj. The Wifiscan now shows the server after changing WiFi.begin to WiFi.softAP, however, the devices still can't send messages via UDP to one another. The WiFi.status is WL_CONNECTED on the client-side, and WL_NO_SHIELD on the server-side. Any other ideas on how to get the ESP32 example code to work?

Comment: WiFi.status is status of the STA

Comment: That makes a lot of sense because the example code is waiting for the other ESP32 to connect in the setup() function. So both should be operating in WIFI_STA mode as it is in the example. However, when running the example neither ESP32 seems to find the other when not in AP mode. Any idea on how to work around this problem and get them to connect?

Comment: either both connect as STA to an AP (WiFi router) or one of the should create the WiFi network with the SoftAP function

Comment: I see, so the ssid and password intended by the example is an external wireless router. When I change those to my home WiFi network on both ESP32s, I can get the client to use udp.broadcastTo and the server-side displays the message. However, the server doesn't seem to use the udp.broadcast to send the client a message. I assume UDP can do two-way communication, so what is preventing the client from receving and displaying the message?

Comment: the client doesn't listen. that is the difference between the client and the server example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In summary, my misunderstandings were:

1. The AsyncUDP example does not allow direct client-server communication. It requires an intermediary router, e.g. a home router. This is because of the WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA) setting - the server needed to be set to WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP) for other ESP32s to be connected to.
2. Both the client and server need to use the udp.listen(port) function to receive messages (where you can specify the port). To send messages, use udp.broadcast(message) for the server and udp.broadcastTo(message, port) for the client.

The following code is the smallest example I could make that still worked. I'm sure there are better examples available, but this is the way I got the example to work to communicate between the two ESP32s without HTTP requests, using an intermediary router, etc...

**The client side:**

```
#include "WiFi.h"
#include "AsyncUDP.h"

const char * ssid = "my_ssid";
const char * password = "my_password";

AsyncUDP udp;

int port = 1234;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA); // Make this the client (the server is WIFI_AP)
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    delay(100);

    Serial.print("Connecting...");
    // Display a period every 0.5 s to show the user something is happening.
    while (WiFi.waitForConnectResult() != WL_CONNECTED) { 
      Serial.print(".");    
      delay(500);
    }
    Serial.println("");

    if(udp.listen(port)) {
        udp.onPacket([](AsyncUDPPacket packet) {
          Serial.print("Received data: ");
            Serial.write(packet.data(), packet.length());
            Serial.println();
        });
    }
}

void loop(){
    delay(1000);
    udp.broadcastTo("A message for the server from the client.", port);
}
```

**The server side:**

```
#include "WiFi.h"
#include "AsyncUDP.h"

const char *my_ssid = "my_ssid";
const char *password = "my_password";

int port = 1234;

AsyncUDP udp;

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(115200);
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
    WiFi.softAP(my_ssid, password);
    delay(100);

      if(udp.listen(port)) {
        udp.onPacket([](AsyncUDPPacket packet) {
            Serial.print("Data: ");
            Serial.write(packet.data(), packet.length());
            Serial.println();  
          });
      }
}

void loop() {
    delay(1000);
    udp.broadcastTo("Anyone here? Love from the server.", port);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just a modest addition to Jeremy's answer.
The text states that server uses `udp.broadcast(message)` while the client uses `udp.broadcastTo(message, port)`
On the other hand, the provided code uses `broadcastTo` both sides.
I was wondering why that and after nosing around in the source code AsyncUPD.cpp I saw that `udp.broadcast` will actually do its job by calling `udp.broadcastTo` using as the second parameter the local port.
Refer to: https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/AsyncUDP/src/AsyncUDP.cpp line 809.
It is a minor detail but I think worth mentioning it. It allowed me to pair ESP32 boards of same type and (most important to me) using same code for the UDP iteractions. Hence, the two boards may work together (hierarchically or not) or autonomously.